# Infrared light therapy for menstrual pains?

Tags: pain, light, menstruation

My wife often has menstrual pains that knock her down for 1-2 days every month. She uses heat packs to make it bearable.

I saw an infrared light on special offer earlier today and considering buying it for her to see if it helps. Wondering if that helps. Vendors don't mention it specifically as a way to use it. Some sites suggest it's a way to use an infrared light. Other sights talking about menstrual pain specifically rarely seem to mention infrared light therapy as an option. So, I'm getting mixed signals.

Going slightly more fundamental, I believe menstrual pain is caused by cramps (uterine muscle contractions) and in some cases inflammation. Both muscle pains and inflammation are said to be relieved by infrared light therapy.

Would appreciate any comments to indicate this working, or not.